# When we are posting post on twitter, I want to send the tweeted post link will be sent via sms to a subscribers stored in a DE using mobile studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, marketingcloudapi, social-studio, mobilestudio

I am stuck in a scenario in SFMC , when we are posting post on twitter, I want to send the tweeted post link will be sent via sms to a subscribers stored in a DE using mobile studio.
I Want to achieve this ,f it is possible.
Any suggestion for would be thankful.

Comment: This is a fairly simple scenario. Simply grab the share link (https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/tweet-and-moment-url) and then include it in the body of your SMS message via copy-paste or personalization from a column in your DE.

Comment: Are you using API call to post a tweet? If so, what is the endpoint and response?

Comment: @JasonHanshaw I want to make to automated instead of manual for every post.

Comment: Create an automation or external microservice to call the Twitter API to retrieve tweets for a given user and then parse the response and upsert the value into a data extension. Then query your audience and the twitter DE to join them and include the stored twitter data as a column in your sendable DE and insert w/ ampscript (or just use a lookup ampscript function call to grab that value at send time).